# NER to recognize custom Entities

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have a requirement to detect company names from the given text. I have trained CRFClassifier, with my training data and gazette data both. After training the classifier, when i use test data, to Identify companies it's not detecting properly. If i gave company name which is part of training data, its able to recognize, if i give any company name that is part of  gazette file, its not able to recognize those entities. Can you help me, how i can proceed further to do it in a right direction to recognize entities.

Property file that i'm Using looks like this

trainFile=training-data.tsv

serializeTo=custom-classification-model.ser.gz

map=word=0,answer=1

useClassFeature=true

useWord=true

useNGrams=true

noMidNGrams=true

maxNGramLeng=6

usePrev=true

useNext=true

useSequences=true

usePrevSequences=true

maxLeft=1

useTypeSeqs=true

useTypeSeqs2=true

useTypeySequences=true

wordShape=chris2useLC

useDisjunctive=true

useGazettes=true

gazette=gazette.txt

cleanGazette=true

**Sample Training Data file**

Warburg COMPANY

Pincus COMPANY

has O

agreed O

to O

acquire O

North O

Carolina  O

- O

based O

Service O

**Gazzette File Data file**

ACON    COMPANY

Investments    COMPANY

LLS    COMPANY

Post    COMPANY

Oak    COMPANY

Energy    COMPANY

Capital    COMPANY

Merrill    COMPANY

Lynch    COMPANY

International    COMPANY

Aion    COMPANY

Direct    COMPANY

Singapore    COMPANY

Answer (score 0):

Your gazette file is not properly formatted.

An example entry should be like:

`CLASS1 this is an example`

There is a more detailed answer on the NER FAQ page:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#gazette